# How can I force intellij to check all files?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I'm using intellij sometimes I do very large refactors that the IDE can't help with. This often breaks a lot of files, but since I'm using either Typescript or Java it's relatively easy to find the problems.

My issue is that I can't seem to get Intellij to check those files unless I open them specifically.

The kind of checking I'm talking about isn't a specific inspection, it's just like the normal compilation problems.

So for example, I have a typescript project and I modified some stuff. When I open some of my React components intellij waits a second, and then highlights parts of it in red. I can go to those parts and see what the issue is.

I've tried forcing the inspector to run, and I've tried building the project, but neither one gives me the red squiggly love I need :^(

It feels like the project->build should force intellij to highlight all this stuff, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Easily one of the most frustrating aspects of IntelliJ. It handles simple renaming very poorly.